# Regular expression for catching equation parameters

Tags: regex, vba

I have a mathematical expression with two groups of parameters:

1. Any combination of letters, digits and special characters
2. Parameters looking like `"HUB_XX"` where `XX` is a numer (one or more digits)

So the formula might look like that: `(a1 * ((bb * HUB_1)+c))+(d * ((e * HUB_1)+f))+13,56`.
My task is to first capture all parameters from first group, meaning everything that is not a mathematical operator (`+-/*()`) or not a `"HUB"` parameter (`HUB_1` in this case) or not a constant (`13,56`). 
In given example that should result in matching: `a1,bb,c,d,e,f`
In next step i'll need to match only parameters looking like `HUB_number`

Second expression is rather simple to write but i'm struggling with the first one.
My working enviroment is VBA (Excel, Access).

Can someone advise on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Paul. I'll check if i can use negative lookaround in VBA. But still if a parameter is a combination of letters and digits (e.g., a1) it's not catched. Ideally only "HUB_number" should be excluded and in your pattern exclussion starts at "HUB_"  level

Comment: Can you demonstrate any effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: That worked! Thank you Paul! You're pure gold:)

Comment: And Scott, I did try to solve that myself. My initial idea was to simply exclude all matching patterns by combining thm using "or" operator. For mathematical operators it worked ([^*|\\||^(|^)|^+|^-]+).

Comment: The problem started when i tried to add "HUB_XX" to the pattern. First of all it treated all the letters separately (so wasn't able to use e.g., H anywhere else. In addition it excluded all other digits (those attached to parameters as well). So the pattern [^*|\\||^(|^)|^+|^-|^HUB_\d+]+ wasn't working (even though without exclussion it was). Basically i was blindly trying to transform that pattern but it led me nowhere. Once again thank you Paul.

Comment: Alright, I posted this as an answer then. Also removing my comments to avoid redundancy. I'll let you mark this as the chosen answer if this really is the solution you're going for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will retrieve your first group of information :

```
(?!HUB_\d+)\b[a-zA-Z][^+-\/*()]*\b
```

Note that the matched parameters must start with a letter.

See this [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WAjyOR/3).

**Edit :** If you want to be able to use greek characters, you should add the \p{Greek} parameter :

```
(?!HUB_\d+)\b[a-zA-Z\p{Greek}][^+-\/*()]*\b
```

Note that you have to use the `u`nicode option for it to work.

See this [other demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZtN65/1).

Comment: One more question. How can i include special characters (α,β,Ω,...)to match the pattern? A parameter can look something like that. So instead of "b" it may be "β".

Comment: @MaciekDziendziel Alright, good to know ! I edited my answer to add greek characters matching.

Comment: I used p{L} to match letters from all alphabets. It works!